# Запятые перед ИЛИ?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены

> Снять с себя, например, одежду или часы или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату.

Нужны ли запятые перед ИЛИ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Снять с себя, например, одежду,** (пауза) **или часы,** (пауза) **или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату.**

Все запятые ставим, они вполне (в виде пауз) передают размышления автора над примерами, которые он  "додумывает" в процессе речи.

Как уже сказано, постановка запятых соответствует правилу для повторяющихся союзов, если союз ИЛИ повторяется хотя бы дважды.

Comment: По контексту: автор не размышляет, а перечисляет. Главное, я понял, что зпт нужны. Спасибо!

Comment: Перечисляют так:  одежду, часы или другую вещь. А тут какой-то дополнительный смысл, интонация или плохое знание языка.

Comment: Скорее последнее, пусть останется на совести автора.

Answer (score 2):

Корректно:

> Снять с себя, например, одежду, или часы, или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату.

Мы имеем дело с однородными дополнениями *одежду, часы, вещь*, соединенными повторяющимся союзом *или... или*. Союз *или* перед первым однородным членом считается опущенным.

Подробнее: https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-pered-soyuzom-ili-stavitsya-zapyataya.html.

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже считаю, что корректно писать так:

**Снять с себя, например, одежду, или часы, или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату.**

Но я вижу другое объяснение. Первая запятая стоит перед присоединительной конструкцией. Так можно объяснить странное повторение союза *или* после слова *например*. Некто сказал: "Снять с себя, например, одежду", а потом добавил: "...или часы, или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату".

Comment: Но ведь тогда должна возникнуть пауза, которую необходимо обозначит: «Снять с себя, например, одежду... или часы, или другую вещь, которая понравилась твоему брату». Разве нет?

Comment: @Aer Запятая — это тоже пауза, правда не такая выразительная. Но на то воля автора.

Comment: Запятая действительно может обозначать паузу, но дело в том, что не всегда ее обозначает. В связи с этим ваша трактовка, может быть, и вероятна, но сильно зависит от намерений автора, тогда как запятая _необходима_ вне зависимости ни от чего.

Comment: @Aer "Запятая необходима вне зависимости ни от чего" >> Если выбирать между запятой и ее отсутствием, то тогда да.